# How can I solve "push" issue?

Tags: git, visual-studio

As you can see in the pic, I am trying to push my changes but I have that error below;

[image: details]

Also, this is the output of the issue:

> Error encountered while pushing branch to the remote repository:
> rejected Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch
> is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes  before
> pushing again.

```
Pushing YE/WI00334762_new
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
git: 'credential-manager-core' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Pushing to https://devops.wisetechglobal.com/wtg/CargoWise/_git/Dev
To https://devops.wisetechglobal.com/wtg/CargoWise/_git/Dev
failed to push some refs to 'https://devops.wisetechglobal.com/wtg/CargoWise/_git/Dev'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I would be glad if someone could help me with this problem.

Comment: Try git fetch and then git pull to pull the changes and then do git push

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hint%3A+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+tip+of+your+current+branch+is+behind

Comment: Or, `git push --force-with-lease` if you are "behind" on your own feature branch due to rebase or amend.

Comment: I tried git fetch but then the pull button is not active to click unfortunately.